# Idiom for automatically creating missing values in map using Java

Tags: java, collections, idioms

I often use maps to store values in loops, such as a set/list of objects pertaining to the same class/group, or an AtomicInteger that I want to increment.  I thus often write the following kind of code (assuming I do not store null in my map):

```
/* Example #1 -- aggregation */
Map<K, Set<O>> map = new HashMap<K, Set<O>>();
for (O o : oList) {
    K k = o.getK();
    Set<O> oSet = map.get(k);
    if (oSet == null) {
        oSet = new HashSet<O>(o);
        map.put(k, oSet);
    } else {
        oSet.add(o);
    }
}

/* Example #2 -- counting */
Map<K, AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<K, AtomicInteger>();
for (O o : oList) {
    K k = o.getK();
    AtomicInteger i = map.get(k);
    if (i == null) {
        i = new AtomicInteger(1);
        map.put(k, i);
    } else {
        i.increment();
    }
}
```

I know of the Apache Common collections `DefaultedMap` which can create a value from a factory/model object on the fly when it's missing; but you rely on (another) external library just for avoiding the (rather small) annoyance of writing 2/3 lines of code.

Is there an easier solution (especially for example #2)? What do you fellow developer use/recommend in that case? Is there other libraries providing this kind of "defaulted map"? Do you write your own decorated map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [MultivaluedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) as part of Java WS to me.

And the same as implemented by [Spring Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html)

So to answer your question, there is no default implementation for this and you have to roll your own or better use one of the implementations.

Answer (score 8):

In Java 8, the method `computeIfAbsent()` was added to the `Map` interface:

> `default V computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction)`
>
> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), the most common usages are to create a new object as an initial mapped value or to implement multi-value maps. For example:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<V>()).add(v);
```

So you could rewrite your examples as follows:

```
/* Example #1 -- aggregation */
Map<K, Set<O>> map = new HashMap<>();
oList.forEach(o -> map.computeIfAbsent(o.getK(), k -> new HashSet<>()).add(o));

/* Example #2 -- counting */
Map<K, AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<>();
oList.forEach(o -> map.computeIfAbsent(o.getK(), k -> new AtomicInteger(0)).incrementAndGet());
```

Another option is to use the Stream API together with [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-):

```
/* Example #1 -- aggregation */
Map<K, Set<O>> map = oList.stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(O::getK, Collectors.toSet()));

/* Example #2 -- counting using a Long instead of an AtomicInteger */
Map<K, Long> map = oList.stream()
                        .map(O::getK)
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(k -> k, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Google's [guava-libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) also provides such a Map implementation. 
But I wouldn't use a library only for such a small benefit. When you already use such a library you could think about using the maps. But in general, and this is only my opinion, I don't like using libraries for trivial things.

The examples in your questions seems fine to me. I'm also using this idiom.